# app:checkedIcon="@null" in MaterialCardView is crashing in Android 9 and lower

Tags: android

I got a Material Card view in the layout like

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:checkedIcon="@null"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:clickable="true">
```

And its crashing in Android 9.0 and lower. It works fine without `app:checkedIcon="@null"` . `checkedIconenabled=false` in styles.xml also does not work. Is there any way in XML other than setting `cardView.checkedIcon = null` in the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crash is because the drawable shouldn't be null

You can solve this by setting a transparent color instead with `app:checkedIcon="@android:color/transparent"`